# Multiple loop functions parallel running in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I've 3 loops i want to be executed in parallel until the exit of program.
Actually I used this solution but i think is not optimal:

```
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, loop,app):
        self.loop = loop
        self.app = app
        self.root = tk.Tk()

    async def show(self):
        while True:
            self.root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

class App:
    async def exec(self):
        self.window = Window(asyncio.get_event_loop(),self)
        await asyncio.gather(self.window.show(), self.connectWS(),self.readSerial())

    async def readSerial(self):
        self.serial = serial.serial_for_url('/dev/cu.usbserial-1430', baudrate=9600, timeout=5)
        self.serial.isOpen()
        self.serial.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        self.serial.flushOutput()
        while True:
            response = self.serial.read(1)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    async def connectWS(self):
        try:
            async with websockets.connect(
                "ws://mysocket.com") as ws:
                self.ws = WebSocketHandler(str(uuid.getnode()), ws,self)
                await asyncio.gather(self.ws.start(), self.ws.send_boot_payload())
        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError:
            print("DISCONNECTED")
            call_later(10,self.connectWS) #reconnect

asyncio.run(App().exec())
```

Can someone suggest me the best practice to execute 3 (or more) loops (actually are a WebSocket, a serial reader and a Tkinter loop that update UI basing on serial and websocket)?

Comment: What about this solution do you think is not optimal? Is it working as intended?

Comment: Yes, but I think multithreading is better then coroutine gather. Consider for example the serial is fast and can block the execution of other loops